# Question on modal logic

Tags: modal-logic

Suppose the sentence *p* is possible, and *-p* is impossible.

Is the disjunction *p* v *-p* necessary?

Comment: *-p is impossible* means *necessarily --p*, i.e. *necessarily p*.

Answer (score 1):

Formal tautologies are always logically necessary. Standard FOL has *p* v *-p* as a formal tautology, hence it is necessary regardless of whether *p* is necessary or possible. This breaks down if you consider alternative logics that don't have the Law of Excluded Middle as a tautology.

Comment: Thanks Era for the reply. Subsidiary question: if 'p' is neither necessary, nor impossible. Is p = p v p necessary?

Comment: @student Can you clarify exactly what you mean by `p = p v p`?

Comment: OK, let's say that, on one hand, p is not necessary, and, on the other hand, p is not impossible. Is p necessary too?

Comment: @student *not impossible* means *possible*. `p` can be possible without being necessary.

Comment: So, if p is either not necessary or possible, is p necessary?

Comment: @student so you're asking whether `((not necessarily p) or (possibly p)) => necessarily p`? The answer is no.